# Why can't I get into my acount?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I went into my Minecraft the first thing I saw was a log in with your email and password I wrote my password, email, and username on paper but when I tried it, it said that it was wrong. I never changed computers and I never reset my password in case it would delete my Minecraft servers and worlds. Help?

Comment: What do you by "my password email and username"?  Did you try a few times to make sure you were typing the required information correctly?

Answer (score -1):

You have to use your email (Not your password!) if that doesn't work just change your passcode.

Also if you can update your launcher you might be using an old one.

If you have an old account you will get migrated to a new one on minecraft.com if you ask for help there.

Eventually it will log out of your account from time to time so you have to memorize your passcode.